# Rearranging a sequence to maximize difference in order, ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, math, sequence

I have an ordered sequence in the form of an array. e.g.

```
original_order = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to know how to re-order the sequence, with the maximum difference in order, with regard to the original order.
Specifically, I want to know what order would give the Maximum "score", when running the code below:

Put simply, the below calculates the distance that each value from the sequence has "moved" in the rearranged sequence (array called rearranged), when compared to its position in the original_order sequence. It then sums the differences (distances moved) for each value, to give an overall score of "difference in order" for the rearrangement. Someone told me that this "score" I am calculating can be defined as the ordinal similarity between the two sequences (original order and rearranged).

I think the max score can be obtained by running the code with the rearranged order as the **reversed** original order. I have not found a method of rearrangement that has a higher score than this, though If anyone thinks I am wrong please let me know (for the example original_order above this would be max_score = 50). I think that no other rearrangement of the sequence order can give a higher score (although there are other orders that give the same score).

```
position = original_order.map{|x| rearranged.index(x)} #works out the index of original_order values in rearranged
index_values = Array(0..(original_order.length - 1)) # array of index values for original_order
both = []
both << position
both << index_values
difference = both.transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:-)} # taking away old position from new position, to find the distance that the value has "moved" when re-ordered
difference_abs = []
difference.each do |i|
    difference_abs << i.abs
end
score = difference_abs.inject(:+)
```

What I would like to know is:

1. if my hypothesis that the reversed order will always give the highest possible score, regardless of the length of the sequence array, is correct
2. a mathematical explanation of what my code does, and why simply reversing the original order gives the highest possible score
3. if ordinal similarity is an accurate way of defining my score metric, and if not, what is?

Also, any tips on simplifying my code are welcome.

Comment: I think you are misusing the word "disorder". It means something else. Use another word, like "rearrangement", "replacement", etc. Also, do not show a chunk of code before explaining what it is. Don't expect people to read through your messy code. You should explain the idea of maximum score before showing the code.

Comment: @sawa Thanks for the input, I have made the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be modelled as an [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

If the original array is {1, 2, 3, 4}, then in the final array, there are 4 positions that need to be filled with a single element each. This results in a 4x4 assignment matrix with the corresponding scores.

```
  positions
   1 2 3 4 
1  0 1 2 3
2  1 0 1 2
3  2 1 0 1
4  3 2 1 0
```

Convert the scores to costs by negating them and adding 3 to all the elements (although as pointed out, adding a constant is not necessary).

```
  positions
   1 2 3 4 
1  3 2 1 0
2  2 3 2 1
3  1 2 3 2
4  0 1 2 3
```

You should be able to apply the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to solve the above assignment problem.
Note that there shall be more than 1 solution.

EDIT: As Cary Swoveland pointed out, the above problem can be solved quickly by a normal LP solving algorithm like the revised Simplex where the variables need not be integers.

Comment: Good for you to recognize this as an "assignment problem".  Just a couple of points: negating the scores to convert them to costs is sufficient; you don't not need to add a constant to make them non-negative; and I believe you are confusing degeneracy (making no improvement at one step of the algorithm) and having multiple optima.

Comment: Want more? This is a linear programming problem (LP).  It is also one type of LP problem called a "transportation problem" (TP), and one type of TP called an "assignment problem" (AP).  One therefore can solve it with any algorithm that can be used to solve general LP problems (the "revised simplex" being the best-known), TP's or AP's.  LP models do not require variables to be integer-valued (`0 <= x <= 1` for the AP), but the simplex algorithm and all specialized algorithms for TPs and IPs are guaranted to produce integer-valued optima.  There will be a quiz on this Friday.

Comment: I discovered a ruby gem called Munkres, that uses a cost matrix like the second one suggested by Abhishek Bansal as input for the Hungarian algorithm. It outputs the positions that each of the values are at in the original sequence array, with the position they should be at in the new order, to minimize the overall cost. As I suspected, the reverse of the original order is the solution that the algorithm suggests. Thanks to Abhishek Bansal and @CarySwoveland for the help.

Comment: ^ ...and here is a link to Munkres in case anyone is interested: https://github.com/pdamer/munkres